# Characterizing simple grassman algebra modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Good day all. I am wondering about a possible classification result.

Consider the Grassman algebra $\bigwedge V$ for a vector space $V$ of finite dimension. Is there a simple characterization of the simple modules over $\bigwedge V$? As in, how can we describe them all up to isomorphism? I did not see this result in my books, so I thought I ask here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted here: [Are projective modules over exterior algebras of vector spaces necessarily free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135107/are-projective-modules-over-exterior-algebras-of-vector-spaces-necessarily-free) the exterior algebra is local, and hence has only one maximal right ideal, call it M. Any simple module must therefore be isomorphic to the right $R$ module $\bigwedge(V)/M$.

Similarly, the simple left modules are isomorphic to the left $R$ module $\bigwedge(V)/M$.